Sorting a subset of a sorted list of points in optimal time
I have n k-dimensional points (modeled as n k-dimensional arrays of doubles). I have also sorted the n points by each of their coordinates. This gives me k lists of the points.
From a subset of the points (say m <= n points) sorted by the i-th coordinate I would like to return a list of the same points sorted by their (i+1)-th coordinate in optimal time.
My ideas are: sorting the subset without using the sorted lists takes O(m log m) time. If I write each of the m points at the position of their (i+1)-th ordering and shrink the structure to remove empty cells, that takes O(n) time. Can I do it in O(m) time?
